# Right site for asking "How to save a web page that is not able to be saved on archive.org?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

**What is the right site for asking "How to save a web page that is not able to be saved on archive.org?"**

**Remark:**

web page = website

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "web page" specially because you say that archive.org can't save that thing. Maybe the following question from [su] could help you to add details to this question [How do I fully save a modern webpage which uses JavaScript (e.g. Facebook), in its intended viewable formatting, for fully offline viewing?](https://superuser.com/q/1762065/152004) or actually already have the answer that you are looking for.

Comment: You find a article on Wikipedia about what a "web page = website" is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website

Comment: Even this question has already two answers with positive score, one of them, mine, I don't see any reason to reopen this question. The body is practically the same as the title, the edit to add the "remark" didn't really improved the question. Worst the [OP's new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386604/289691) doesn't show any progress in question quality as the the title and body had the same problem of the original revision of this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Wayback Machine can be regarded as a web application, and [Web Applications Stack Exchange has 38 questions about it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org). Your question looks similar to this one: [Why does archive.org say that this URL is not available?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94525/136642)

Comment: With the details provided by the OP, the question doesn't look to be about using a web application, i.e. archive.org. I dont' think that **nowadays** the question might be a good fit for for Web Applications because  questions about technologies that make web apps work are off-topic as well questions that asks to find or recommend one. The referred question looks like one of the still open [tag:broken-windows].

Comment: Maybe it's a gray area? The problems they have may be caused by the specific website, but there may be a workaround, which another WebApps.SE user knows *because* they have much experience in using the Wayback Machine. Or know that it's fruitless, and suggest alternatives like https://archive.today.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm having *exactly* the same question as the OP here since 6-8 months, for https://www.hardloopuitslagen.nl/?wedstrijd&show=645 (I ended up 2nd place in the full marathon) - I get "Save Page Now browser crashed on URL https://www.hardloopuitslagen.nl/?wedstrijd&show=645.", but Archive Today works for me.

Comment: Putting aside the question, what are you saying in the answer is correct, Wayback Machine is a web application, there are 38 questions in [webapps.se] about it. I don't know if the OP question is similar to the one that you pointed as it's not clear what is the storage to be used, what is the save format, etc. I wouldn't say that you have the exactly the same question as you are providing more details . Please me let me know if you would like a site recommendation :)

Comment: P.S. Troubleshooting questions are off-topic in [webapps.se], they might be on topic in [su] if the OP do their "homework" (they might get guidance on chat rooms / per-site meta )

Comment: Just made [wayback-machine] that has 10 questions a synonym or [archive.org]. It will take a bit for the stats to be updated.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question is closed, can you please reopen?

Comment: I disagree with the reopening. Added a comment about this to the question.

Comment: I have a conflict of interest, so I don't feel comfortable casting a binding reopen vote. FWIW, the new question by the OP is completely irrelevant in that decision. We should judge posts by content only.

Answer (score 2):

**About the clarification added to the question**

> web page = website

The feature "Save page now" of archive.org's Wayback Machine  only allow to save single pages from websites that allow web crawling. To automatically add a website to archive.org you might have to use their API or might have to install software / join The Archive Team. Questions about using the API might be on topic in Stack Overflow. If you have problems installing software you might ask questions about them on sites like Super User.

Ref. [SAVE PAGES IN THE WAYBACK MACHINE](https://help.archive.org/help/save-pages-in-the-wayback-machine/).

---

**Regarding questions in Meta SE**

While there is no question length requirement and Meta SE is less strict than Stack Overflow and other SE sites, please don't just drop a single statement questions (title and body are practically the same).

**Regarding this specific question**

"How to save a web page that is not able to be saved in archive.org"

Technically a web page is an hypertext document delivered by web server. As there are no details about the problem, there is no way to know if the "web page" could be saved in archive.org or in another place.

On the early days of the Web, most of the the content available to everyone were *web pages* but nowadays it's very rarely to find *web pages* in a strictly sense. If the content that you want to save is hold in a real web page and the server has no included measures to prevent that it be saved, first we need that you clarify where do you want to save this web page:

- *if you want to save it in archive.org*, there might be chances that the you should contact one of the involved parties or both. Customer service questions are off-topic in Stack Exchange Network.
- *if you want to save it anyware*, you should be able to save it by using the built-in function of your web browser to save it to a local storage device. Questions about using a web browser might on topic in Super User, Ask Different if it's about using Apple hardaware/software, and probably other sites about operative systems.
- *if you want to ask for an alternative to archive.org* (another web application), you might ask a question in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and there might be chances to make get a recommendation on Web Applications SE but you should follow the guidance provided in the corresponding per-site Meta.

  - [Alternatives to archive.org](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45379/14228) (from Software Recommendations)
  - [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163) (from Meta Web Applications)

In order to be able to give you a specific guidance, IMHO, besides the storage target we need other details. It might be helpful to have at least one specfic example including information about how you learned that  archive.org was not able to save it.

Sites like Stack Overflow, Super User and Web Applications are  not well suited for people who know nothing about computers, so you will have better chances that your question will be "well received" if it shows an understanding of the pretty basics of what is being asked, i.e., the difference between a web page and a web application (you might use the term that you prefer, but it should be clear what you mean).

In Super User there is a recent question (posted in January 2023) that might be related to what you are trying to ask

[How do I fully save a modern webpage which uses JavaScript (e.g. Facebook), in its intended viewable formatting, for fully offline viewing?](https://superuser.com/q/1762065/152004)

**Regarding the recommendations based on tags and questions**

Please bear in mind that the tags and questions migth be [broken-windows](/questions/tagged/broken-windows).

- Site scope might change over time. If you have doubts, ask in the per-site meta.
- Not all the tags are on topic. The tag wikis might be "wrong" (not according to the site scope) . If you have doubts, ask in the per-site meta.
- Not all questions having upvotes and / or answers are on-topic according to the current site scope. If you have doubts, ask in the per-site meta.

Note: To ask in the per-site metas users should have reputation >= 5. Users having reputation >20 on other Stack Exchange sites might look at the site chat rooms. Per-site's main chat room might people willing to help new users learn about the site scope and the site workings.

**About [[archive.org]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org)**
Tag of Web Applications SE

- This tag had 4 questions posted in the last year (deleted questions are not included). All of them have score 0, answers 0. Only one has comments. It has one comment.
- This tag has 38 questions. 35.8% are unanswered.
- The answerer with more answers have posted 4 answers.
- The answerer with the top score has 18.
- The asker with more questions have posted 3 questions.
- The asker with the top score has 25.

Questions asking "why" that can't be converted to "how to" i.e. they are asking about the root cause of an error, or about technology, capacity, policies, or other stuff that only  the web application developers can answer nowadays are off-topic in Web Applications SE. Because of this, [Why does archive.org say that this URL is not available?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94525/88163) that was referre in the [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386466/289691) was closed.

Also the tag excerpt was updated to add the recomendation given in the How to ask a good question, tailored for this tag by, besides asking searchig Web Applications SE, pointing the askers to search https://help.archive.org before asking a question.

**Troubleshooting**

When a problem happens with a web application like Wayback Machine, it might need necessary to do some *troubleshooting*.

Unfortunately [troubleshooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting) like questions are off-topic in Web Applications but they might be on topic in other sites like Super User by following the per-site guidelines as questions that require a lot of back and forth, as usually troubleshooting might require, are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Below there are few questions about asking troubleshooting questions

*Super User*

- [2023 stand about "troubleshooting"](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14888/152004)
- [Looking for a canonical about troubleshooting issues about using web aplications?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14891/152004)